# How to define conditional mapping in Mapster with different types of source field?

Tags: c#, mapster

I'm trying to use Mapster for mapping and can't use conditional mapping in case of different field types in different condition 'branches'.

For example there are 2 classes:

```
public class Source
{
    public int? IntValue { get; set; }
    public string StringValue { get; set; } = "Some Value";
}

public class Destination
{
    public string Mapped { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

The task is put in `Mapped` string representation of `IntValue` if it's not null, otherwise use `StringValue`. I assume configuration should look like ([according to Mapster docs](https://github.com/MapsterMapper/Mapster/wiki/Custom-mapping#mapping-with-condition)):

```
TypeAdapterConfig.GlobalSettings
    .NewConfig<Source, Destination>()
    .Map(dest => dest.Mapped, src => src.IntValue, src => src.IntValue.HasValue)
    .Map(dest => dest.Mapped, src => src.StringValue);
```

But it gives runtime exception:

```
Mapster.CompileException: Error while compiling
source=Source
destination=Destination
type=Map
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: No coercion operator is defined between types 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]' and 'System.String'.
```

Of course I can just slap `.AfterMapping()` and perform anything with custom code, but is there Mapster way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The way you are using the map method is correct. The error is because the third parameter expression does not support the use of `.HasValue()`.
The way to solve it is to compare it against the null value.

Solution:

```
TypeAdapterConfig.GlobalSettings
    .NewConfig<Source, Destination>()
    .Map(dest => dest.Mapped, src => src.IntValue, src => src.IntValue != null)
    .Map(dest => dest.Mapped, src => src.StringValue)
```

I ran into a similar problem, trying to parse an enum to long in the validation expression.